# Passing value from master to corresponding sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have google sheet collecting data from 7 other sheets of the same structure. Each of the sheet has its own owner, they fill the info and the final column is the "approved" col that they leave empty.

Now what I want to do is to be able to approve those rows from the master sheet.
Master sheet collects the info from the other sheets using query and multiple importrange functions and filter out rows that have null value in the first column or have a "approved" column = 'yes'.

So what I want to happen is approving those rows from the master and as soon as that happens they should disappear from master. What's the best way to create communication that communication? This is probably important - combination of 3 columns would create a unique id of the row.

Sheet 1

```
Date         Name Sheet Approved 
2020-01-01   A       1       
2020-01-02   B       1       Yes
```

Sheet 2

```
Date         Name Sheet Approved 
2020-01-01   C       2       
2020-01-02   D       2
```

Sheet 3

```
Date         Name Sheet Approved 
2020-01-01   E       3      Yes 
2020-01-02   F       3
```

Master

```
Date         Name Sheet Dummy* Approved 
2020-01-01   A       1       
2020-01-01   C       2       
2020-01-02   D       2       
2020-01-02   F       3
```

*Using dummy to filter out rows already approved

and now as soon as I add approved in Master for name A, I want that cell to change in sheet 1 (and using my query function filter it would disappear from the Master)

Master

```
Date         Name Sheet Dummy* Approved 
2020-01-01   A       1         Yes
2020-01-01   C       2       
2020-01-02   D       2       
2020-01-02   F       3
```

Sheet 1

```
Date         Name Sheet Approved 
2020-01-01   A       1       Yes
2020-01-02   B       1       Yes
```

Master

```
Date         Name Sheet Dummy* Approved 
2020-01-01   C       2       
2020-01-02   D       2       
2020-01-02   F       3
```

Any ideas or directions?

Per suggestions - added links to sheets I already have (limited to 2 owners since it doesn't matter atm)

**Master**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a6XoQvmGNSq3D0t5eaVXHoYBmSTVhn4T7GUMdmscWvE/edit?usp=sharing

**Owner1**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hjs7hoKqDEsGEdyMmWRlrlBer4w7dcV4TH8I1FSvwjk/edit?usp=sharing

**Owner2**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WJ1LiZixmrtla3BFAaUOWyQ_SfFfZIT-I38138X4cNE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Would you consider providing a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on?

Comment: @Iamblichus as you suggested added example sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure many solutions exist, my thought would be to have the other 7 sheets import to a tab in the owner's sheets. Then in each owner's sheet for the Approved cell write a query to return the Approved column from the imported sheet using the combination of 3 columns that create the unique id of the row.

**Update:**
I am working with the shared sheets you shared and I added a tab to the Owner 1 sheet to import the data from the master. I then added a formula in F2 for sheet1:

```
=if(isna(query(MasterImport!$A$1:$F,"SELECT F WHERE A = date '"&TEXT(A3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND B ='"&B3&"' AND C = '"&C3&"' LABEL F ''",1)),"",query(MasterImport!A2:F,"SELECT F WHERE A = date '"&TEXT(A3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND B ='"&B3&"' AND C = '"&C3&"' LABEL F ''",1))
```

However, it seems to be creating a circular reference of sorts and Sheets keeps showing and removing so this approach will not work.

So, I added a tab to the master sheet importing all owner sheets where the date col is not null and changed the query range in sheet1 to the OwnerImports tab.

```
=QUERY(OwnerImports!A2:F, "select * where F is null",0)
```

I also changed the formula in the owner sheet to query the OwnerImports tab instead of Sheet1.

```
=if(isna(query(MasterImport!$A$1:$F,"SELECT F WHERE A = date '"&TEXT(A3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND B ='"&B3&"' AND C = '"&C3&"' LABEL F ''",1)),"",query(MasterImport!A2:F,"SELECT F WHERE A = date '"&TEXT(A3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND B ='"&B3&"' AND C = '"&C3&"' LABEL F ''",1))
```

I believe it is working. You would mark the row Accepted in the OwnerImports tab and it is reflected in the Sheet1 tab.

There does seem to be some lag on the owner sheet, refreshing the sheet helps. This was a hairy one!

Comment: any tips how to return approved column from the imported sheet? this is what I struggle with, normally it would be a join, but query function doesn't have it.

Comment: Share your sheet and one owner sheet, view only and I will provide you a working example.

Comment: Great, I updated my answer and the sheets, seems to be working.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much